# Can I build a prediction neural network model with only one input?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, regression

I have set of images that were cropped from videos, 2 frame shots per second. Based on that I do detect response time according to a specific color in these images. by summing how many frames without response time.. till the next image that has a response time.

Anyway, I do store this response time( which is only numbers into a numpy array) and i need to build a model to predict the response time... do i need to build a regression model? what do you advise?

Hope my question was clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question directly, can you *build* a neural network with one input.

Technically, sure, you can physically construct a NN with one input note. However, this is going to be utterly useless at actually *predicting* anything.

Consider the mathematical underpinning of what a neural network is. It's a linear algebra expression:

```
W = [w(0,0), w(0,1) ... w(0,n)
     w(1,0), w(1,1) ... w(1,n)
     ...
     w(k,0) ...         w(k,n)]

a = [a(0), a(1), ... a(n)]

bias = [bias(0), bias(1), ... bias(n)]

s = some normalizing function

such that:

b = s(W*a+bias)
```

Now say we compressed this down to a single input node. What happens to our network expression?

it turns into the function for a line! That's not something you can 'train' with a data set. There's nothing *there* to train!

So in order for a neural network to be effective, we need to structure our data set in a way which can be distributed over a large set of nodes.

I'm not entirely sure what the problem set here is, but your first step needs to be normalizing the structure of your data. Whether it's an interval time, RGB values over a set of pixels, I don't know; without seeing the data or some code it's kinda hard to offer help past this point. But there's some general advise going forward.

Best of luck!